# Function in template class vs template function

Tags: c++11, templates

When we have a function template like this:

```
template <class T>
void push_back(T&& type)
{

}
```

It is perfectly legal, to call it like this:

```
push_back(1);
```

and like this:

```
int i = 0;
push_back(i);
```

But, when I have a template class:

```
template <class Type>
class List
{
public:
 void push_back(Type&& value)
 {
 }
};
```

I cannot call it like this:

```
  List<int> list_int;
  int i = 42;
  list_int.push_back(i);
```

because I am getting the folllowing:

```
 error: rvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to lvalue of type 'int'
```

Would someone explain to me why, please?

Answer (score 3):

In:

```
template <class T>
void push_back(T&& type)
```

`T&& type` is a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), that binds to any [value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

Whereas in:

```
template <class Type>
class List
{
public:
 void push_back(Type&& value)
 {
 }
};
```

`Type&& value` is an r-value reference, that only binds to r-values.

To make `List::push_back` use forwarding references `push_back` must be made a function template:

```
template <class Type>
class List
{
public:
 template<class U>
 void push_back(U&& value)
 {
 }
};
```

Or, in C++20, use `auto&&` parameter type:

```
template <class Type>
class List
{
public:
 void push_back(auto&& value)
 {
 }
};
```